# msysgit git-am can't apply it's own git format-patch sequence

Tags: git, git-svn, patch, msysgit

I'm using *msysgit* git on windows to operate on central svn repository. I'm using git as
I want to have it's awesome little local branches for everything and rebasing on each other.

I also need to update from central repo often, so using separate svn/git is not an option.

Problem is - `git svn --help` (man page) says that it is not a good idea to use `git merge` into *master* branch (which is set to track from svn's *trunk*) from local branches, as this will ruin the party and `git svn dcommit` would not work anymore.

I know that it's not exactly true and you may use `git merge` if you are merging from 
branch which was properly rebased on *master* prior merge, but I'm trying to make it safer and actually use `git format-patch` and `git am`. We are using code review, so I'm making patches anyway. I also knew about `git cherry-pick`, but I want to just `git am /reviewed/patches/dir/*` without actually recalling what commits was corresponding to this patches (without reading patches, that is).

So, what's wrong with `git svn` and `git am`? It's simple - `git am` for a few very hard points is doing *CRLF* into *LF* conversion for patches supplied (`git-mailsplit` is doing this, to be precise), if not rebasing. `git format-patch` is also producing proper (LF-ended) patches.

As my repo is mostly *CRLF* (and it should remain so), patches are, obviously, failing due to wrong EOL. Converting diffs to *CRLF* and somehow hacking `git am` to prevent it from conversion is not working, too. It will fail if any file was removed or deleted - `git apply` will complain about expected /dev/null (but he got `/dev/null^M`).

And if I'm applying it with `git am --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace` that it will
commit LF endings straight to the index, which is also weird. I don't know if it will preserve over commiting into svn (via `git svn dcommit`) and checking it out and I don't want to try out.

Of course, it's still possible to try hacking around patches to convert only actual diffs, but this is too much hacks for simple task.

So, I wonder, is there really no established way to produce patches and apply them to the same repo on the same system? It just feels weird that *msysgit* can't apply it's own patches.

Comment: Had a similar problem a while ago and solved it using `git am --keep-cr` IIRC...

Answer (score 3):

```
git format-patch --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace

git am --keep-cr --ignore-whitespace
```

This helped me. You can get a better understanding if you read this .